# Freeradius: No reply message for Failed Authentications

Tags: linux, configuration, radius

I have configured freeradius on RHEL 6.5 server for MAC based authentications and for this, I've followed [this guide](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/mac-auth).

According to the mentioned guide, I have created `authorized_macs` file for the valid MAC addresses as below:

```
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx    Reply-Message = "Device with MAC Address %{Calling-Station-Id} authorized for network access"
yy-yy-yy-yy-yy-yy    Reply-Message = "Device with MAC Address %{Calling-Station-Id} authorized for network access"
```

I've tried to make certain changes in `authorize` section of `/etc/raddb/sites-available/default` file, in order to set `Reply-Message` for failed authentications, as below:

```
authorize {
  preprocess

  # if cleaning up the Calling-Station-Id...
  rewrite.calling_station_id

  # now check against the authorized_macs file
  authorized_macs
        if (!ok) {
        update control {
              Reply-Message := "Login Failed. MAC Address %{Calling-Station-ID} is NOT valid."
            }
            reject
        }
        else {
            # accept
        users
            update control {
              Auth-Type := Accept
            }
        }
}
```

When configuration is tested using `radclient`,

Successful authentication:

```
> echo "Calling-Station-Id=xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx" | radclient -s localhost:1812 auth testing123

Received response ID 55, code 2, length = 93
        Reply-Message = "Device with MAC Address xx-xx-xx-xx-xx- authorized for network access"

           Total approved auths:  1
             Total denied auths:  0
               Total lost auths:  0
```

Failed Authentication:

```
 > echo "Calling-Station-Id=zz-zz-zz-zz-zz-zz" | radclient -s localhost:1812 auth testing123

Received response ID 220, code 3, length = 20

       Total approved auths:  0
         Total denied auths:  1
           Total lost auths:  0
```

In case of unsuccessful authentication, no `Reply-Message` is displayed.

What should I do if I need to enable messages for Access-Reject responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Reply-Message` in an **`update reply`** block, rather than `update control`. Using your example:

```
        update reply {
              Reply-Message := "Login Failed. MAC Address %{Calling-Station-ID} is NOT valid."
            }
```